# How to use 2 shells for a python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, curses

I have a python project that I use curses. I would like to open another shell for piping some of my outputs, how shall I achieve this?

Clarification:

I am writing a TUI using Curses module of python. Therefore my initial bash shell is a curses window.

I would like to have live updated variables in another bash shell if that's possible for debugging purposes.

What I am asking is, if there is a way to make a python program open another shell and pipe the standard output to that shell, instead of the default shell which in my case is the window for the curses environment.

Comment: Could you pleas elaborate what you want to do? It is a bit unclear

Comment: I tried to clarify the question upon your request.

Comment: Do you mean you want 2 Terminals open with a `curses`-controlled display running in each? Or one `curses` window and another Terminal which just shows scrolled text? Or something else?

Comment: I mean one terminal using curses another terminal just shows scrolled text as in your second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities.

---

Start a second Terminal window, and in there run:

```
tty
/dev/ttys000       # sample output - note down for next command
```

In the first Terminal where you run `curses`, do:

```
echo "Hi" > /dev/ttys000
```

---

Alternative method... make a fifo with:

```
mkfifo fifo
```

In a second, new Terminal, run:

```
while : ; do cat fifo; done
```

In the first Terminal, run:

```
echo "Hi" > fifo
```

---

Alternative method... tail a file.

In your `curses` Terminal, append messages to a file:

```
echo "Message" >> log.txt
```

In your other Terminal, follow the tail of the log file:

```
tail -f log.txt
```